# Randomize texture position by frame

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I would like (for an electricity shader) to randomize its Location by frame...
I know Object Info has a random output but not sure how to change that value each frame.
Any idea?

Thanks[image: Nodes for electricity random]

Answer (score 3):

You could add a fourth dimension to your Noise and Voronoi texture and control the W dimension with #frame driver. Just write #frame to the value field.

[image: Driver]

The frame driver is probably too fast so you could divide it by 100.

[image: Scale]

[image: Result]

Comment: In fact what I need is a vey different result each frame so even I have to multiply the #frame value. Very interesting solution. Thank you very much!!